# How could I find this item using selenium by this text in between the span?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to find this item by this text in-between :

[image]

I currently have the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


options=Options()
driver=webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    
#Directing to site
driver.get("https://www.amazon.co.uk");

#Searching and navigating to search page
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/span/form/div[3]/span[1]/span/input"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/header/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/div[1]/input"))).send_keys("Nintendo Switch")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/header/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/form/div[3]/div/span/input"))).click()

#Locating item on page
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(., 'Nintendo Switch (OLED Model)')]"))).click()
```

however there seems to be a mistake here. What would be the correct way of rewriting this?

Comment: driver.findElement(By.id("Nintendo Switch (OLED Model)"))
 is the Java syntax and your tag is showing python, Please update the tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David,

This line of code that you've

```
#Locating item on page
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(., 'Nintendo Switch (OLED Model)')]"))).click()
```

here xpath `//span[contains(., 'Nintendo Switch (OLED Model)')]` has 5 entries in HTML-DOM.

How you can verify the same?

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath`, you'd see `1 of 5 entries`

That's why your code is not working properly. `xpath` should locate `unique` entry in `HTML-DOM`. If it has multiple entry it will always select the first node.

So changing your xpath to `//a//span[contains(., 'Nintendo Switch (OLED Model)')]` should filter the element to 1 of 3. Now this element will get the click `Nintendo Switch (OLED Model) - White`.

If your intention is to pick `Nintendo Switch (OLED Model) - Neon Blue/Neon Red` then use this XPath

`//a//span[contains(., 'Nintendo Switch (OLED Model)') and contains(text(),'Neon Blue/Neon Red')]`

and same for another web element as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Works flawlessly. I shortened it slightly into this: element=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a//span[contains(., 'Nintendo Switch (OLED Model) - Neon Blue/Neon Red')]"))).click()

Answer (score 0):

`driver.findElement(By.id("Nintendo Switch (OLED Model)"))` is the *Java* syntax and possibly you need *Python* syntax.

---

### Solution

To print the text ***In stock.*** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *XPATH* and *innerText*:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Nintendo Switch (OLED Model)']")))
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and *`contains()`*:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(., 'Nintendo Switch (OLED Model)')]")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Hi thank you for your response. I used the XPATH method you shared. I added a .click() at the end. I can't seem to get it to click on the item. Perhaps I am doing something wrong.

Comment: I have included the full code at the top now.

Comment: any ideas on how i could fix this?